# Laravel Form: Allow user to add multiple products at a time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form where the user has to select a product from dropdown and enter the qty used. I want the user to be able to add multiple products at a time. I need help in processing this data.

This is how I have done it so far. I have kept 6 pairs of fields and the user has to fill in the first but others are optional, here is the blade code.

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'parts.raw.store', 'id' => 'raw-part-form' , 'class'=>'raw-part-form','name'=>'raw-part-form' ]) !!}
@for($in=0;$in<6;$in++)
    <div class='col-md-7'>
        <label for="raw_material_id"{{$in}}>Packing Material</label>
        {!!  Form::select('raw_material_id'.$in, $raw_materials
              ->lists('display_name','id')->prepend('',''),null,
              ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'raw_material_id'.$in])!!}
     </div>
     <div class='col-md-5'>
          <label for="qty_used{{$in}}">Qty used</label>
          <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control"
          id="qty_used{{$in}}" name="qty_used{{$in}}" placeholder="Qty Used"">
     </div>
@endfor
```

[image]

I am not sure if this is a good approach. I am also confused how to process it in the controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

For blade:

```
            @foreach ($foods as $k => $food) // or 1 to 6
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="number" name="item[{{$k}}][qty]" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="item[{{$k}}][id]" value="{{$food->id}}">
              </td>
              <td>{{ $food->name }}</td>
              <td>{{ $food->price }} €</td>

              <td>
                <a href="/cart/add/{{$food->id}}">+</a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Controller:

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
{
  $input = $request->all();

  foreach ($input['item'] as $item) {
    $this->ValidQtyCheck($item['qty']); // >0 or remove it
    $food = Food::findOrFail($item['id'])->toArray();
    Cart::add($item['id'], $food['name'], $item['qty'], $food['price']);
  }

  return redirect('/cart/view');
}
```

And pro tip, for dinamic adding instead of 6 always: [pro tip](https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery)

---

> Validating Arrays
>
> Validating array form input fields doesn't have to be a pain. For
>   example, to validate that each e-mail in a given array input field is
>   unique, you may do the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
    'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
]);
```

[Validating Arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays%20validate%20arrays)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How should I modify my validation rules. 

`'item[0][raw_material_id]' => 'required|exists:raw_materials,id',` gives 400 bad method error

Comment: You have to place them inside a foreach loop, like foreach item as valid, valid => required...

Comment: Wow I didn't know about the wildcard new feat. Glad you asked